# Question put on hold, but why? | Topic: Potential Hardware Solutions to a given problem

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold

I posted for the first time at SU looking for advice on potential solutions to a problem at hand, https://superuser.com/questions/775782/potential-inexpensive-standalone-display-system.
While it may appear on the surface to be a "what should I buy?", that was not my intention. However, it was put on hold within a minute.

I may have misunderstood on what constitutes a valid question, in which case I would appreciate some feedback on how to improve my question. If the question is not for SU to begin with, any suggestions on where to seek help would help too.

Comment: Please note that we have [raspberrypi.se] and they also have a chat.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Noted, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I closed that, and I felt that that it was a hardware recommendation question, amongst other things.

You're asking for 1. Hardware 2. You have a price range in mind. Its a hardware recommendation question, even if you're asking about a class of hardware.

It was also a question that seeked to poll for options - In other words, as per the help center

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer
>   set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Between these two reasons, I'm pretty convinced this was the right thing to do.

I did make one error here. I should probably have pointed you at [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), our main chatroom were we do, fairly commonly talk about stuff like that.

Comment: +1 for articulating that nicely. I understand the situation better now and realize it wasn't a question for SU. I'll check out Root Access as well in the hope I can get some help there.